# Linked List, skipping every nth amount user inputs

Tags: python-3.x

This code is part of a file where I am manipulating a linked list. This section is part of a function called alternate(head, skip_amt). The user will call the alternate function in a separate file to test my functions. The user will enter a list of nodes and the skip_amt. If the user enters skip_amt = 3, then my function needs to skip over 3 nodes in the linked list and return the 4th node until the end of the list.

My function below is doing this correctly for 0 steps, 1 step, and 3 steps. How can I change my function so that if the user wants me to skip every nth node and return the (n + 1)th node until the end of the list? I also feel like this code is too long and there must be a shorter way to accomplish what I am trying to do.

```
def alternate(head, skip_amt):
    if (skip_amt == 0):
        head = head.next  
        return head 
    
    if (skip_amt == 1):
        temp = head
        if (temp):
            #  if list has nodes
            head = temp.next
            temp = head

            while (temp and temp.next):
            #  skips every other item in linked list a
            #  removes pointer so old_head returns every other item
                temp.next = temp.next.next
                temp = temp.next

            return head  
            
    if (skip_amt > 1): 
        
        temp = head.next.next
        
        if (temp):
            
            #  if list has nodes
            head = temp.next
            temp = head

            while (temp and temp.next):
            #  skips every other item in linked list a
            #  removes pointer so old_head returns every other item
                temp.next = temp.next.next
                temp.next = temp.next.next.next 
                temp = temp.next
                
                
            return head
```

Comment: Could you share how you are calling your alternate() function?

Comment: Can you please fix the indentation of the code?

Comment: my instructor wrote the test case on how to call my function, and created another file creating a list_node.py file. List_node constructs a single node in a singly-linked list. He said we don't need to know how to write/construct a single node but be able to manipulate the singly-linked list. I don't think I can post his work on here since I did not write it :/

Comment: I already don't understand the `skip_amt == 0` case. Why do you still skip the very first node?

Comment: in this part, that means we do not skip anything at all and return the original linked list as is. When i tried to return head as is, it only returns the first node. When I added head.next, it iterates through and returns every node in the list.

Comment: I don't understand what "it" is in the phrase "it iterates through". The thing is that you are not including the very first node in this way.

Comment: OH, I can' t believe I completely didn't see my mistake there. I think I was burnt out from staring at the same piece of code all day long . Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, there is no reason why you should treat separately the case where `skip_amt` is 0, or is 1, or is 2... You can do this in one generic way.

Here is some code you could use. I have included utility functions to convert a sequence (i.e. list, range, tuple) to a linked list, and to iterate a linked list.

I would also define `alternate` as a method. Things become a bit easier if you also define a separate method that walks a given number of steps forward in the list.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next
    
    @staticmethod
    def fromsequence(seq):
        head = None
        for val in reversed(seq):
            head = Node(val, head)
        return head

    def __iter__(self):  # allow iteration over this linked list
        node = self
        while node:
            yield node.val
            node = node.next

    def forward(self, steps):  # return the node that is `steps` ahead
        node = self
        for _ in range(steps):
            if not node:
                return
            node = node.next
        return node

    def alternate(self, skip_amt):
        head = self.forward(skip_amt)
        node = head
        while node:
            node.next = node.forward(skip_amt+1)
            node = node.next
        return head

#  demo
head = Node.fromsequence(range(17))
print(list(head))  # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
head = head.alternate(3)
print(list(head))  # [3, 7, 11, 15]
```

Comment: I am not familiar with linked list, still have a lot to learn about them... The TA I was working with was leading me down a different and messier path. I didn't think about separating the functions to make my code easier to read! Whoa, thank you so much. I know my question was a bit confusing. . . The way you set it up makes a lot more sense to me. Thank you I really appreciate your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Needs some tweaking, but it would be along the lines of this

```
def alternate(list, skip_steps): 
    print('list head:', list.data)
    if (skip_steps == 0):
        while True:
          print(list.data)
          if(list.next == None):
            print('end of list')
            return
          list = list.next
    elif (skip_steps == 1):
        while True:
          print(list.data)
          if((list.next== None or list.next.next== None)):
            print('end of list')
            return
          list = list.next.next
    else: # Means we have to skip steps > 1
      while True:
        for i in range(skip_steps):
          if(list.next == None):
            print('end of list reached before next node')
            return
          list = list.next
        print(list.data)
```

You should be able to modify it to work for your needs